Ros2_control for specific kind of 4wd
I have a 4wd Keyestudio ks0223 smart car kit. Unfortunately, the port on the motor drive shield for the left rear wheel is not working, so I connected the left rear wheel motor to the same port as the right rear wheel drive. In essence, I now have a 4wd where the front wheels are independent, but the rear wheels will move together and have the same velocity and all. Please, how can I control using ros2_control.

How should that work? Your car is a diff-drive kinematics, left and right wheels have to rotate differently to be able to turn. you could connect all left and all right wheels together, then you can configure a classic 2-wheeled  diff_drive vehicle.
